# Passing a variable inside s nested loop

Tags: powershell

I'm tying to work out how I pass a variable from an if statement into a nested if statement starting at:

> If ($server -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME)

```
Foreach ($comp in $computer) {

    $server = split-FQDN $comp -part H
    $domain = Split-FQDN $comp -part D  

    #Set the domain based parameters

    If ($domain -eq '1.fqdn.com') {
        set-domparams $domain $userprompt $userpass
    }

    Elseif ($domain -eq '2.fqdn.com') {
        set-domparams $domain $userprompt $userpass
    }

    Elseif ($domain -eq '3.fqdn.com') {
        set-domparams $domain $userprompt $userpass
    } 

    ElseIf ($domain -eq '4.fqdn.com') {
        set-domparams $domain $userprompt $userpass
    } 

    ElseIf ($domain -eq '5.fqdn.com') {
        set-domparams $domain $userprompt $userpass
    } 

    ElseIf ($domain -eq '6.fqdn.com') {
        set-domparams $domain $userprompt $userpass
    } 

    If ($server -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME) {
        $server = $_
        #clear Kerberos ticket cache
        Invoke-Expression -Command:'cmd.exe /c klist purge' | Out-Null
        $buildlogsuccess = check-buildlog $domain
        $chocologstatus = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {check-choco}
        $KMSvalues = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {get-winlicense}
        $parentOU = get-ParentOU (Get-ADComputer -Server $dc -SearchBase $searchbase -Filter {name -eq $server} -Credential $fetchCreds) | select -expand parentou
        $SCCMcheck = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {get-sccmstatus} 
        $scomcheck = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {get-scomstatus} -argumentlist $scom
        $AV = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {get-avstatus}
        $wfirewall = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {(get-service MpsSvc).status}
        $net35 = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {(Get-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Core).installed}
        $admins = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {check-admins} 
        $DomainComms = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {get-domaininfo}
        $bigfix =  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {get-bigfix}
    }

    Else {
        $server = $_
        #clear Kerberos ticket cache
        Invoke-Expression -Command:'cmd.exe /c klist purge' | Out-Null
        #start running functions against target server(s) to get required info
        $PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $comp -Credential $fetchCreds -Name $server
        $buildlogsuccess = check-buildlog $domain
        $chocologstatus = Invoke-Command -Session $pssession -ScriptBlock ${function:check-choco}
        $KMSvalues = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-winlicense}
        $parentOU = get-ParentOU (Get-ADComputer -Server $dc -SearchBase $searchbase -Filter {name -eq $server} -Credential $fetchCreds) | select -expand parentou
        $SCCMcheck = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-sccmstatus} 
        $scomcheck = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${function:get-scomstatus} -argumentlist $scom
        $AV = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-avstatus}
        $wfirewall = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {(get-service MpsSvc).status}
        $net35 = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {(Get-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Core).installed}
        $admins = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:check-admins} 
        $DomainComms = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-domaininfo}
        $bigfix =  Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-bigfix}
        #clean up the remote session
        Remove-PSSession -Name $server
    }
```

I already have some global variables in use that are passed by a loaded function, but I'm trying to avoid do the same for this bit of code and understand how to pass my remaining variables ($comp, $computer and $domain) correctly to the next inner loop.

I've tried getting $server to work doing the following but haven't had any success as of yet:

> $server = $_

Comment: I don't see an inner loop, can you clarify what you mean? There's no need to use `$_` (in fact its probably empty, unless there's some outer pipeline function or loop you haven't shown). `If` statements don't have any specific scope, you should just continue to use the variables you've been using.

Answer (score 2):

This is more [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) opinion instead of an answer, but anyway.

Instead of long `if...elseif` constructs, why not use [table driven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/105311) programming? If there are lots of domains and they require different credentials, maintaining the `if...elseif` is tedious. Store the credentials in custom Powershell objects and those in a hashtable. Then lookup can be done with the domain name only. Like so,

```
# Declare a hashtable and add custom credential objects
$creds=@{}
$creds.Add('foo.fqdn', $(New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'Domain'='foo.fqdn'; 'User'='foo.user'; 'Pass'='foo.pass'}))
$creds.Add('bar.fqdn', $(New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'Domain'='bar.fqdn'; 'User'='bar.user'; 'Pass'='bar.pass'}))
$creds.Add('zof.fqdn', $(New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop @{'Domain'='zof.fqdn'; 'User'='zof.user'; 'Pass'='zof.pass'}))

# Later when credentials are needed, check if the domain is present
# and get the values from the hashtable.
if($creds.ContainsKey($domain) {
  set-domparams $domain $creds[$domain].User $creds[$domain].Pass
} else {
  write-warning "Domain $domain not found!"
}
```

Comment: Thanks vonPryz, that's much appreciated & something that will come in handy.

I should have mentioned that the u/n & password objects are created & stored as part of an imported function that generates various domain objects & constructs queries from a hash table of values.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a non-question as your variables are valid within the loops/statements they are created.

```
Foreach ($comp in $computer) {

    $server = split-FQDN $comp -part H
    $domain = Split-FQDN $comp -part D

    if($true){
       # $comp, $server and $domain are all in scope
       Write-host "$comp $server $domain"
           if($true){
               # also true in nested if statements
               Write-host "$comp $server $domain"
           }
    }
    Else{
       # $comp, $server and $domain are all in scope
       Write-host "$comp $server $domain"
    }
}
# outside, $comp is not available, only $computer
# $server and $domain will only contain the values from the last run of the foreach loop.
```

Comment: Thanks all. Don't know if something else was going on that made it look like variables weren't being passed properly, but seem ok now.